# Site is visiting itself every 15 min

Tags: wordpress, apache, security, server

Looking for some help here on why my website visits pages and xml sitemaps every 15 mins.

Check out my screenshot here:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10729686/wordfence.png

Any ideas why this is happening? Should I block my IP from itself lol - Wordfence my security plugin requested that I block it but I havn't blocked it yet, I've just been watching what it decides to visit?

Is this something from the YOAST plugin perhaps - I dunno :(

Thanks for any help!
-Spencer

Answer (score 1):

*I'm not sure about this*

The "browser id"  is `w3 total cache`. My guess is that W3 is checking for pages/updates and visiting them to keep the cache up to date.

Are you using W3? how often does this happen? Does this continue to happen when W3 is turned off?

Comment: I've checked it out and disabled w3 total cache and it still does it. It happens about every 15 min. I also noticed that not all the items, even when w3 total cache is enabled, are even labeled...Any way to tell if this is eating significant server resources, or if I can just ignore it?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'd recommend asking your hoster to check this. Something is "pretending" to be w3. Are you on a shared host. If so this can come from everywhere.

Comment: No, right now its a Digital Ocean droplet. I manage it right now. It just started doing it about a week ago :(